# double dispatch infinite loop

Tags: c++, pure-virtual, virtual-functions, double-dispatch

I'm using double dispatch to obtain the distance between 2 objects of 2 classes(`B`, `C`) that are subclasses of another (A).
I think that the methods in `class A` should be pure virtual, but them are used in a test elsewhere, so the `class A` must be instantiable, so I can't make them pure virtual, right?

Another thing is that I'm not sure if I'm using double dispatch in a good way, since sometimes generates a infinite loop, in the definition of `Distance(A *a)` in the base class.

In the `class A`, I have the methods:

```
virtual double Distance(A *a)  {return a->Distance(this);}
virtual double DistanceB(B *b) {return std::numeric_limits<double>::max();}
virtual double DistanceB(C *c) {return std::numeric_limits<double>::max();}
virtual double DistanceC(B *b) {return std::numeric_limits<double>::max();}
virtual double DistanceC(C *c) {return std::numeric_limits<double>::max();}
```

In the `class B`:

```
double B::Distance(A *a)  { return a->DistanceB(this); }
double B::DistanceB(B *b) { /*calculate distance*/ }
double B::DistanceC(C *c) { return c->DistanceB(this); }
```

In the `class C`:

```
double C::Distance(A *a)  { return a->DistanceC(this); }
double C::DistanceB(B *b) { /*calculate distance*/ }
double C::DistanceC(C *c) { /*calculate distance*/ }
```

Comment: Pretty please with strawberries and a cherry on top, format code as code.

Comment: It would help people if you describe what triggers the infinite loop (show which method you're calling and how, i.e. with which arguments).

Comment: `double A::Distance(A *a) {return a->Distance(this);}` looks suspicious.

Comment: Following may help if you can use C++11 : https://ideone.com/8VxALs

Answer (score 0):

```
virtual double Distance(A *a)
{return a->Distance(this);}
```

So if I have:

```
A* a1, a2;
```

And I call:

```
a1->Distance(a2);
```

The aforementioned implementation will call

```
a2->Distance(a1);
```

Which will call:

```
a1->Distance(a2);
```

...And that's an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since `A` is not pure abstract, you have to provide also :

```
virtual double DistanceA(A *a);
virtual double DistanceA(B *b);
virtual double DistanceA(C *c);
virtual double DistanceB(A *a);
virtual double DistanceC(A *a);
```

And fixing

```
double A::Distance(A *a) {return a->DistanceA(this); }
```